# Toggle (enable / disable) all checkboxes in an HTML table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add an `Enable all` checkbox in an HTML `<table>`, that toggles all checkboxes inside that `<table>`.

I can't get it to work.

#### My Jquery :

```
var elementName = 'TestName';

$('input[familyname="TestName"]').on('click', function() {
    if ($("input[familyname='" + elementName + "']").is(':checked')) {
        $(this).find('tr').nextAll('tr').find('input').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $(this).find('tr').nextAll('tr').find('input').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

See also [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m5a60um/3/).

---

#### Update:

I got it to work with this code:

```
var elementName = 'TestName';
var $checkboxes = $('.table-list').find('input'); 

$('input[familyname="TestName"]').on('click', function() {
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

However, there is bug when I want to add more tables. See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5m5a60um/25/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple but optimal way to achieve the desired effect, that works for any number of checkbox groups :

```
var elementName = 'TestName';

$('input[familyname="' + elementName + '"]').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this)
        .closest('.table-list')
        .find('input')
        .prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/e8jxv8sg/17/))

Comment: It works but if i want to have 2 tables in same time like this https://jsfiddle.net/5m5a60um/25/

Comment: @EdinPuzic : Just add some IDs and it works fine. Also, make sure all of your IDs are unique! Check out this Fiddle here --> https://jsfiddle.net/5m5a60um/26/

Comment: @JohnSlegers Will you create 100 event handlers if there are 100 tables? :\

Comment: @JohnSlegers It works but the probles is that I will have more then 30 tables on one page.

Comment: @EdinPuzic Why can't you use the approach given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749279/select-all-checkbox-in-table/35749527#35749527)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy : You're totally right. I was making this too complicated ;-)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy : Even your version can be simpler, though. See my latest update for what I'm pretty sure is the most optimal version ;-)

Comment: @EdinPuzic : I just updated my answer, yet again, with a solution that's even simpler than Rajaprabhu's ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your code like below,

```
var elementName = 'TestName';
$('input[familyname="' + elementName + '"]').on('click', function() {
  var elems = $(this).closest('table.table').find('tr input');
  elems.prop('checked', this.checked)
});
```

`tr` is parent in our context, so `.find()` over `$(this)` will not work out. So we have to use `.closest()` to grab the parent table and from that we can fetch all the required input - check box elements.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5m5a60um/16/)

---

You have same id set with two radio buttons, give unique id to radio button and use the above code.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5m5a60um/29/)

Comment: It works but if i want to have 2 tables in same time?

Comment: @EdinPuzic It would be better to answer if you show the entire html

Comment: @EdinPuzic Just give different id to that enable all check box and its label. Check this demo. https://jsfiddle.net/5m5a60um/28/

Comment: @EdinPuzic By the way, Try to press the tick mark inside anyone of the answers here. As it will help the future visitors to spot a worked out answer for them. And this is not a compulsion. :)

Comment: Thank you very very much!! :)

Comment: @EdinPuzic Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are putting in `thead` then you can't just directly do `.find()` instead traverse to `tbody` and select all `input` with `type=checkbox`, like:

```
 $(this).closest("table").find('tbody input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
```

Similarly do:

```
 $(this).closest("table").find('tbody input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: It works but if i want to have 2 tables in same time?

Comment: I dont understand, what do you mean by 2 tables in same time? @EdinPuzic

Comment: Like this, I have different 2 tables with enable all button https://jsfiddle.net/5m5a60um/27 and I need to separate enable all button. Now when i click on table number 1 it enables table number 2 also

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).on('click', '#switchall1', function() {

if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr input').prop('checked', true);

}
else {
    $(this).closest('table').find('tbody tr input').prop('checked', false);
}
```

});